# Cannot embed struct in struct

Tags: go

I have the following two structs:

```
type Profile struct {
    Email        string   `json:"email"`
    Username     string   `json:"username"`
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Permissions  []string `json:"permissions"`
}

type Session struct {
    Token  string   `json:"token"`
    User   Profile  `json:"user"`
}
```

and I'm trying to create a new `Session` using:

```
session := Session{token, profile}
```

where `token` is a string and profile is a `Profile` both created earlier.

I'm getting the error **cannot use profile (type *Profile) as type Profile in field value** when I compile.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `profile` is a pointer. Either redefine your `Session` to be

```
type Session struct {
    Token  string    `json:"token"`
    User   *Profile  `json:"user"`
}
```

or dereference it.

```
session := Session{token, *profile}
```

Comment: Thanks - what does derefencing actually mean then?

Comment: When you dereference a pointer, you get the value the pointer (which is an address) was pointing to. The type `*Profile` is an address of a `Profile` value. `*p`, where `p` is of type `*Profile`, will get the value.